# How to filter list of dictionaries by certain Keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have the following list:

```
list = [{'Jim': {'age': 20, 'lastname': 'Smith'}}, {'Sarah': {'age': 25, 'lastname': 'Jones'}}, {'Bill': {'age': 30, 'lastname': 'Lee'}}]
```

I want to be able to filter `list` by Key, so for example if i want the the Sarah dict, i want the output to be that dictionary. for example:

```
output = {'Sarah': {'age': 25, 'lastname': 'Jones'}}
```

Comment: `{k: v for x in d for k, v in x.items() if k == "Sarah"}`

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Iterating the list? Checking a list items keys meets your criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `filter` function in python to do this :

```py
my_list = = [{'Jim': {'age': 20, 'lastname': 'Smith'}}, {'Sarah': {'age': 25, 'lastname': 'Jones'}}, {'Bill': {'age': 30, 'lastname': 'Lee'}}]

filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: 'Sarah' in x, my_list))
```

The first parameter is a function itself that take as argument each element of the list and return a boolean saying if the element should be kept.

Comment: So this was partly the correct answer, I just needed to throw the filter inside ```list()```. Would look like this: ```filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: 'Sarah' in x, my_list))```

Answer (score 0):

we can use a for loop to iterate over the list. doing so, we get a dictionary in each loop iteration. with the membership operator `in` we can check for the presence of the name.

```
lst = [{'Jim': {'age': 20, 'lastname': 'Smith'}}, {'Sarah': {'age': 25, 'lastname': 'Jones'}}, {'Bill': {'age': 30, 'lastname': 'Lee'}}] 
search = "Sarah"
for outer_dict in lst:
    if search in outer_dict:
        print(outer_dict)
```

output is: `{'Sarah': {'age': 25, 'lastname': 'Jones'}}`